# creating a new textview programmatically below an edittext

Tags: android, textview

I have an activity with an edittext and a button, the former one having the attribute

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

When I press the button, a new textview is created programmatically. I want the new textview to appear under the edittext.
With the code that I have, each textview is created on the right of the button. How can I make it appear where I want, on a new line?
I guess, since the textview is created by code, the only way is programmatically.

Here is my activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    >
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint"
     />
    <Button android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my java code:

```
public class New_set extends AppCompatActivity {
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private EditText mEditText;
private Button mButton;

public static int integer = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_set);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.new_formulas);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_hint);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(mEditText.getText().toString());
}

private OnClickListener onClick() {
    return new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    };
}

private void createNewTextView(String text) {
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(integer);

    textView.setText(text);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 =new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    if (integer > 1)
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, integer - 1);
    else
        params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.add_hint);

    layout.setLayoutParams(params1);
    mLayout.addView(textView);
    integer +=1;

}
```

}

I try to do it with addRule and RelativeLayout, but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your xml and activity code

Comment: create a linear layoute below in EditText and then create run time textview and add this linear layoute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    >

    <Button
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        />
    <EditText
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/add_hint"
        android:id="@+id/add_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/add_hint"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now every child `TextView` you can add to the `hints` `LinearLayout` just like you did above, no need to use rules.

**Important:** When you use `LayoutParams` always use it from the parent layout. For example here it should be `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: there is only a problem: the android:layout_weight="1" doesn't work and the edittext is shrinked at maximum possible. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
private void createNewTextView(String text) {
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setId(integer);

    textView.setText(text);

    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mLayout.addView(textView,1);
    integer +=1;

}
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to add multiple textviews, I suggest you to add a ListView and then add the textviews inside the listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/new_formulas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/add_hint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/add_hint"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is not what I exactly want, because I want the new textview to appear below the edittext...

Comment: no, I want edittext and button on one line, and the textedit below edittext, on another line. the answer of @torque203 is ok, except that now the edittext doesn't take all the space possible on the line..

Comment: Yes that is. Did u try this xml

Comment: @Helios83 you didn't change the orientation that's why you get single line android:orientation="vertical" in linearlayout

Comment: so the first linearlayout should have a vertical orientation and the second one horizontal, right?

Comment: yes you are right. @torque203 also right. this xml just modified your base xml.